# How can i map through an array of object in redux in the reducer.js file to delete a user

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am trying to delete a user in redux. My issue is that when i use map in the reuducer.js file I get a 'state.users.map is not a function' error. I have narrowed it down to the array being made up of objects, so map wont work. I have been struggling to find a way to make it work. The is the first attempt at deleting for the project and the first time this error is showing. I do use 'user.map in a different part to display users to table (userTable.js) and that works fine. Error appears when i press the delete button to try to delete user. Get request works fine. Delete request errors out.

reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {


isFetchingAuth: false,
  isAuthenticatedUser: validateSession(),
  isLoggingOut: false,
  isLoggedOutSuccess: false,
  authObj: getSessionAuthObj(),
  isNewCourseAdded: false,
  users: [],
  lessons: [],
  isAddingNewUser: false,
  isNewUserAdded: false,
  error: ""
};

case GET_USERS_REQUEST:
      return {...state, users: [], error: null}
case GET_USERS_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, users: action.payload, error: null}
case GET_USERS_FAILURE:
      return {...state, error: action.payload}

case DELETE_USER_REQUEST:
    return {
      ...state,
      users: state.users.map(user => 
        user.id === action.id
          ? { ...user, deleting: true }
          : user
        )
    }
case DELETE_USER_SUCCESS:
    return {
      users: state.users.filter(user => user.id !== action.id)
    }
case DELETE_USERS_FAILURE:
    return {
      ...state,
      users: state.users.map(user => { 
        if (user.id === action.id) {
          const { deleting, ...userCopy } = user;
          return { ...userCopy, deleteError: action.error }
        }
        return user
      })
```

This is what is inside my 'users' inside my array and I am trying to get the id number.

0: Object { id: 1, first_name: "JOHN", last_name: "DOE", … }

1: Object { id: 2, first_name: "JANE", last_name: "DOE", … }

2: Object { id: 4, first_name: "CHUCK", last_name: "BARTOWSKY", … }

store.js

```
const store = createStore(
reducer,
  initialState,
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), composeWithDevTools())
);
```

how it shows up on redux devtools

```
users[] => {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "JOHN",
      "last_name": "DOE",
      "email": "johnnydoe@email.com",
      "confirmed": false,
      "active": false,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "JANE",
      "last_name": "DOE",
      "email": "janiedoe@email.com",
      "confirmed": true,
      "active": false,
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "CHUCK",
      "last_name": "BARTOWSKY",
      "email": "chuckb@email.com",
      "confirmed": true,
      "active": false,
    }
  ]
}
```

userTable.js

```
users.map((user) => (
    <Table key={user.id}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{user["first_name"]}</td>
          <td>{user["last_name"]}</td>
          <td>{user["email"]}</td>
          <td>
            <Button id={ user.id } onClick={() => handelDelete(user.id)}>Delete</Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
```

Comment: It seems there is no error in that part of code you shared. Could you please more info about the store and the whole reducer file?

Comment: From what I can tell, `state.users` is an array in the three places referenced in your reducer in the snippet. Yes, please provide more context around the reducer code, the initial state, etc... and a set of steps or dispatched actions to reproduce the error.

Comment: I suspect this is unrelated to the issue but you have an error in the delete users failure section where you’ve typed “student =>“ instead of “user =>”

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good practice to make that kind of process on your actionscreation file, also try to print the value of state.users to see if that variable is the array you're specting. I see you're not getting error with the filter functions, and that could be becouse you're throwing and exception before, then, it would be great if you print the users in every case and also return some hardcoded array while you're checking your main information

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this

```
Object.entries(users).map(user => user[1].id === action.id ? { ...user, deleting: true } : user)
```

Object.entries will make the object enumerable

[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm what's coming through `action.payload` in this case because I think this would be causing the problem.

> case GET_USERS_SUCCESS:
> return {...state, users: action.payload, error: null}

Comment: [link]https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50435657172_328d673053_w.jpg                                                 this is whats coming through the payload. so it looks like its a array inside of an object? Is it still possible to delete a user the way I am trying then?

Comment: It's an array inside object so then assign array not object through reducer because according to your code `user` if of array type

Answer (score 0):

If the `GET_USERS_SUCCESS` payload is `{ data: [...] }`

[image]

then the reducer logic for that case should be

```
case GET_USERS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    users: action.payload.data, // <-- unpack the data from the payload!
    error: null,
  }
```